# scanf() prevents runtime error when inside conditon block

Tags: c

Why does this program run [correctly](https://ideone.com/A7oVzp)

```
s,x="%d";
main(a,t){
for(scanf(x,&t);t--&&scanf(x,&a);)
    s+=(a>0)*a;
printf(x,s);
}
```

And this program doesn't , and gives a [Runtime Error](https://ideone.com/bF4arv)

```
s,x="%d";
main(a,t){
for(scanf(x,&t);t--;s+=a*(a>0))
    scanf(x,&a);
printf(x, s);
}
```

My second program works only if I give `return 0;` at the end.
What is it that putting `scanf()` inside  the condition block makes it work ?

### Sample Input :

```
4
5
-5
6
-1
```

Comment: Please do not write code in this way.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Dont worry its for a code golf competition :)

Comment: Then I believe you know the answer to this _depends_ on lot of things. :-)

Comment: No bro I don't :( That why I asked.Even if you mention one of the reasons then I wouldn't mind

Answer (score 0):

```
s,x="%d";
main(a,t){
for(scanf(x,&t);t--;s+=a*(a>0))
    scanf(x,&a);
printf(x, s);
}
```

This one do not work due to 
for(scanf(x,&t) **;t--;** s+=a*(a>0))

Your stop condition is `t--`, you are going to do an endless loop.

Comment: Nope it will loop till `t-- == 0`